# jquery inputmask regex. Поле либо пустое, либо состоит из 10 символов. Как?

Tags: jquery

нужно на jquery inputmask regex сделать проверку поля ввода.
Поле может быть либо пустым либо заполнено 10 (десятью) символами
Как это сделать с помощью jquery inputmask regex

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
$('#input_element').inputmask('Regex',{
    regex: "\\w{10}|^$", onKeyValidation: function (result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```